# Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $

Tags: math, latex

I have this written in my report, it comes up with this error:

> Missing $ inserted.
>
> <inserted text>
>
> $

Code:

```
\begin{equation}

\epsilon = \frac{u^2}{T} = \frac{L^2}{T^3} \label{eq:1}\\

\upsilon = \frac{L^2}{T} \label{eq:2}\\

\text{Therefore, from equations \ref{eq:1} and \ref{eq:2} we can see that:}\\

\frac{\upsilon}{\epsilon} \sim T^2\\  \therefore T \sim \Big(\frac{\upsilon}{\epsilon}\Big)^\frac{1}{4} \label{eq:3}\\

\upsilon \epsilon \sim \frac{L^4}{T^4}\\  \therefore u \sim (\upsilon \epsilon)^\frac{1}{4} \label{eq:4}\\

\text{Thus from Speed = \frac{\text{Distance}}{\text{Time}} and equations \ref{eq:3} and \ref{eq:4}}:

\eta = u_{\eta} T_{\eta} \sim \Big(\frac{\upsilon^3}{\epsilon}\Big)^\frac{1}{4}\\

\epsilon_{\eta} = \frac{\upsilon}{T_{\eta}^2}\\

\epsilon_{0} = \frac{u_{0}^3}{L_{0}}\\

Re_{\eta} = \frac{u_{\eta} \eta}{\upsilon}\\

Re_{0} = \frac{u_{0} L_{0}}{\upsilon}\\

\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong forum, there is a TeX forum on stackexchange.

You are not allowed to have empty lines in math environments. My solution is to put the line breaks on such lines, so that they are mostly empty.

```
\begin{equation}
%
\epsilon = \frac{u^2}{T} = \frac{L^2}{T^3} \label{eq:1}
\\
\upsilon = \frac{L^2}{T} \label{eq:2}
\\
```

etc.